# How to retain onTouchEvent while touching screen?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I have the following method to handle when I touch the screen:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    boolean touchDown = true;
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i(TAG,"touching the screen: YES");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchDown = false;
            Log.i(TAG,"touching the screen: NO");
    }
    return touchDown;

}
```

The result of the Logcat when I touch the screen without removing my finger is:

```
touching the screen: YES
touching the screen: NO
```

I don't want show the second log until I release myfinger from the screen.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `break;` in your first (and second) case. I've been stung by that, too. :)

Comment: oh I don't know how I could forget this. it bounces! thank you very much

Comment: Just another good reason to use midfunction returns.  If your ACTION_DOWN case had said, simply, `return true`, this would not have happened.